# phpunit - mockup variable (other class object) of tested method.

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I want to test function myFunction which creates some other object.

For example:

```
class sourceClass{
    function myFunction(){
        $other_object = new otherClass();
        if($other_object->someMethod() == 'want to controll it'){
            return 'want this to get';
        }
    }
}
```

Then I want to test myFunction():

```
class StubTest extends TestCase{
    function testMyFunction(){
        $this->sourceClass = new sourceClass();
        $this->assertEquals('want this to get', $this->sourceClass->myFunction()));
    }
}
```

Because function someMethod belongs to other class I can not easy (if at all) controll what it returns. And this is what I need to do for properly run the test. Alternatively If I could somehow mockup the $other_object variable which is made in myFunction.
Is it possible?

Comment: just search around, this question gets asked on a regular basis. short answer -- make the code more testable via DI

Comment: You can use runkit library http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php

Comment: I realized that it is better to prepare all the data in the test database in such a way that the functions return reliable data.